# Find string and datetime difference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to find out how long to take from first process to second process, and second process to third process. The different in the table is lotid, device type and slots. There is multiple string i need to find in the table.

- Process 1- Load Lot Clicked
- Process 2- Q-check Started using 'Q-Check' Button for Lot ID KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 Device Type Mamba-6HR-CC3E
- Process 3-Q-check Started using 'Start' Button for Lot ID KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 Device Type Mamba-6HR-CC3E
- Process 4- Run Proc Selected for lot KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 slots 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,"

This is what my db looks like:

```
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
|          Time         |                                                    Process                                                     | Oven | Line |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
| 10/1/2018 8:45:45 AM  | Load Lot Clicked                                                                                               |    2 | 4072 |
| 10/1/2018 8:47:22 AM  | Q-check Started using 'Q-Check' Button for Lot ID KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 Device Type Mamba-6HR-CC3E     |    2 | 4073 |
| 10/1/2018 8:47:22 AM  | - slots = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,"                                                             |    2 | 4074 |
| 10/1/2018 8:47:34 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M5674_DRV_V53.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 16 needing reload"     |    2 | 4075 |
| 10/1/2018 8:47:37 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M567x_V053_1.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 16 needing reload"      |    2 | 4076 |
| 10/1/2018 8:51:29 AM  | Close Selected from BIB screen for lot                                                                         |    2 | 4077 |
| 10/1/2018 8:51:31 AM  | BIB Screen opened on slot 1                                                                                    |    2 | 4078 |
| 10/1/2018 9:02:04 AM  | Close Selected from BIB screen for lot                                                                         |    2 | 4079 |
| 10/1/2018 9:02:44 AM  | Q-check Started using 'Q-Check' Button for Lot ID KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 Device Type Mamba-6HR-CC3E     |    2 | 4080 |
| 10/1/2018 9:02:44 AM  | - slots = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,"                                                       |    2 | 4081 |
| 10/1/2018 9:02:57 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M5674_DRV_V53.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 18 needing reload"     |    2 | 4082 |
| 10/1/2018 9:03:00 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M567x_V053_1.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 18 needing reload"      |    2 | 4083 |
| 10/1/2018 9:07:01 AM  | Close Selected from BIB screen for lot                                                                         |    2 | 4084 |
| 10/1/2018 9:07:04 AM  | Q-check Started using 'Start' Button for Lot ID KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 Device Type Mamba-6HR-CC3E       |    2 | 4085 |
| 10/1/2018 9:07:04 AM  | - slots = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,"                                                       |    2 | 4086 |
| 10/1/2018 9:07:19 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M5674_DRV_V53.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 18 needing reload"     |    2 | 4087 |
| 10/1/2018 9:07:22 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M567x_V053_1.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 18 needing reload"      |    2 | 4088 |
| 10/1/2018 9:09:31 AM  | Cancel Proc Selected for lot KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1                                                     |    2 | 4089 |
| 10/1/2018 9:09:43 AM  | BIB Screen opened on slot 1                                                                                    |    2 | 4090 |
| 10/1/2018 9:09:55 AM  | Close Selected from BIB screen for lot                                                                         |    2 | 4091 |
| 10/1/2018 9:10:38 AM  | Q-check Started using 'Start' Button for Lot ID KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 Device Type Mamba-6HR-CC3E       |    2 | 4092 |
| 10/1/2018 9:10:38 AM  | - slots = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,"                                                       |    2 | 4093 |
| 10/1/2018 9:10:53 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M5674_DRV_V53.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 18 needing reload"     |    2 | 4094 |
| 10/1/2018 9:10:56 AM  | - Completed Loading C:\masters\winapps\MBI\diags\M567x_V053_1.s19, 0 retries with 0 of 18 needing reload"      |    2 | 4095 |
| 10/1/2018 9:12:58 AM  | - Run Proc Selected for lot KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1 slots 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21," |    2 | 4096 |
+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+------+
```

Comment: Pictures of data aren't helpful; if you're going to supply data, supply it as `text`. Also, when posting a question, it's really important to actually ask one (seems rather obvious to say, right? ); you haven't here you've just stated your goal. What is your question? What have you tried so far? What were the problems/errors you encountered?

Comment: Click on any cell, press CTRL + A, press CTRL + SHIFT + C and paste it in a text file and tidy up. Paste the tidy up data here. Do not post screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I think in essence you want to clean up your data and pull out your key fields.  Then you'll be in a position to calculate your metrics.

Here is a query (based on your sample data) to do this.  It's ugly as you like, but will get the job done, mostly.

The results of running this query against your test data are below.  I'm not sure how to interpret the repeated 'key' at stage 3, nor how to interpret the fact that your 'Proc Selected' line doesn't include the Device Type, which you state is a key attribute.

So by necessity, I leave any refinement, and any calculation of elapsed times up to you, @sapkoklu.

Note: I am assuming that the `Q-check` lines and their associated `slots` lines will have exactly the same timestamp, as is the case in your sample data.

```
-- the first CTE just pulls the rows of the log that you need to identify your steps.
;with cte ([Time], Process, Oven, [LineNo])
as
(
    select * from SourceDataTable
    where Process like '%Load Lot Clicked%'
       or Process like '%Q-check%'
       or Process like '%- slots%'
       or Process like '%Run Proc Selected%'
)
-- The second cte joins the first cte to itself, so we can get the slots along with the lotId and DeviceType.
-- Then we pull out the key fields to enable further analysis.
-- We also add the "step" to make life a bit easier for ourselves.
, cte2 ([Time], Process, Oven, [LineNo], LotId, DeviceType, Slots, Step)
as
(
    select c1.*
    , iif(c1.Process like '%Q-check%',           substring(c1.Process, charindex('Lot ID', c1.Process) + 7, charindex(' ', c1.Process, charindex('Lot ID', c1.Process) + 8) - charindex('Lot ID', c1.Process) - 7) ,
        iif(c1.Process like '%Run Proc Selected%', substring(c1.Process, charindex('for lot', c1.Process) + 8, charindex(' ', c1.Process, charindex('for lot', c1.Process) + 9) - charindex('for lot', c1.Process) - 8)                     
                , null))
    , iif(c1.Process like '%Q-check%', substring(c1.Process, charindex('Device Type', c1.Process) + 12, 255), null)
    , iif(c1.Process like '%Run Proc Selected%', SUBSTRING(c1.Process, charindex('slots ', c1.Process) +6, len(c1.Process) - charindex('slots ', c1.Process) - 6)
        , SUBSTRING(c2.Process, charindex('slots =', c2.Process) +8, len(c2.Process) - charindex('slots =', c2.Process) - 8))
    , case 
        when c1.Process like '%Load Lot Clicked%' then 1
        when c1.Process       like '%''Q-Check'' Button%' then 2
        when c1.Process   like '%''Start'' Button%' then 3
        when c1.Process    like '%Run Proc Selected%' then 4
      end
    from cte c1
    left join cte c2
           on c1.Oven = c2.Oven
          and c1.[Time] = c2.[Time]
          and c1.[LineNo] < c2.[LineNo]
    where c1.Process not like '%- slots%'
)
select [Time], Step, Oven, [LineNo], LotId, DeviceType, Slots from cte2
```

Results:

```
Time                    Step  Oven  LineNo  LotId                          DeviceType       Slots
----------------------- ----- ----- ------- ------------------------------ ---------------- ---------------------------------------------
2018-10-01 08:45:45.000 1     2     4072    NULL                           NULL             NULL
2018-10-01 08:47:22.000 2     2     4073    KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1  Mamba-6HR-CC3E   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,
2018-10-01 09:02:44.000 2     2     4080    KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1  Mamba-6HR-CC3E   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,
2018-10-01 09:07:04.000 3     2     4085    KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1  Mamba-6HR-CC3E   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,
2018-10-01 09:10:38.000 3     2     4092    KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1  Mamba-6HR-CC3E   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,
2018-10-01 09:12:58.000 4     2     4096    KLMHA3760600N31ETTM002SP2REB1  NULL             1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,21,
```

Comment: Hi Brett, I try run your code at sql store proc, and it got me, error "incorrect syntax near the keyword 'like'.". Im a newbie in sql server, but i found out iif statement must have 3 parameters in bracket isn't?

Comment: I've copied the script back into my environment and it works as expected.  Which version of SQL Server are you using?  I'll post a SQL Fiddle link for you..

Comment: I use sql server 17

Comment: You say in your first comment that you ran this as a stored proc.  Have you confirmed that the script works 'as is' without alteration (other than perhaps the source table name / columns that I've assumed in the first cte expression)?  If so, then it sounds like you've introduced an error when you have wrapped it up as a stored proc.

Answer (score -1):

use LEAD analytic function. It returns values from the next row in the table.

LEAD ( expression [, offset [, default] ] )
OVER ( [ query_partition_clause ] order_by_clause )

Comment: This is basically a copy/paste from the documentation of [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). When posting, it's good to cite your information, but also provide the OP with usable examples, normally specific for their needs.